# setHomeUpAsEnabled not working as expected

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I was trying to prepare an application and I used app bar layout to add an app bar, I added the setHOmeUpAsEnabled after defining the app bar in my java code then I also defined the parent activity name in my android manifest file but whenever I am trying to use the back button on the app bar my application just crashes. Below is the code.

```
 mToolBAr =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.reg_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolBAr);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Account");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Out of curiousity - any error log on that crash - or just magically jumping off?

Comment: What's the crash log

Comment: yeah in the logcat assignParent to null: this = DecorView@86153d4[RegisterActivity] this appears

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
     mToolBAr =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.reg_toolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Account");
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
     setSupportActionBar(mToolBAr);
```